# C# Polymorphism - Accessing Properties of child class that aren't in the parent

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm running into issues with being able to call functions/properties that are unique to the child class. I'm wondering if there is a way to do do something similar to the following:

```
public class Creature
{
   public int HealthPoints {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int AttackValue {get; set;}

   public Creature();
}

public class Magical : Creature
{
   public int Mana {get; set;}
}
```

So, in this rudimentary example, I'd have a list of Creatures and would need to be able to call from that the Mana property of any given Magical creature.

Comment: I guess you are talking about casting? `((Magical)myCreature).Mana = 10;`.

Comment: make sure you check if the object is of that type first, then do what Uwe sugests

Comment: Casting here is a hack, and a code smell. Casting will work around your problem but it isn't a *true* fix. You need to refactor your code so you don't need to know *which* type of `Creature` an object is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The short answer:

As you have surely seen in other answers, you can access the `Mana` property of magical creatures as follows:

```
foreach (Creature creature in creatures)
{
    if (creature is Magical magical)
    {
        // ... do something with 'magical.Mana' here...
    }
}
```

### Going a step further:

Since we're talking about polymorphism already, you should know that `if (x is SomeType) { .. }` can be a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Let's say you indeed have a `foreach` loop for processing all your creatures. It might then be better to create a virtual method in the base class, and do whatever you're doing inside the `foreach` loop in that virtual method. You would then override the method in your `Magical` class and thereby get rid of the `if` statement.

Let's do an example. Let's say, all your creatures get hit and lose some energy. Normal creatures lose health points, while magical creatures lose mana:

```
public partial class Creature   // rest of your class is omitted in this example
{
    public virtual void TakeHit()
    {
        // whatever you had in your original foreach loop, e.g.:
        HealthPoints--;
    }
}

public partial class Magical : Creature
{
    public override void TakeHit()
    {
        // ... any special processing for Magical creatures goes here, e.g.:
        Mana--;
        // (you could also call 'base.TakeHit()' in this method.)
    }
}
```

Your original `foreach` loop now becomes much simpler:

```
foreach (Creature creature in creatures)
{                        // note: no more if statement -- The virtual method
    creature.TakeHit();  // invocation now takes care of distinguising
}                        // different (sub-)types of Creatures!
```

I would like to recommend a very nice presentation on this very topic to you: [***Conditionals and Polymorphism***](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=d449gch_62ckrb4zgj).

Comment: +1: Thank you, I started writing an answer to this effect but got dragged away by the real world. The sooner I win the lottery, the sooner I'll be done with such pesky interuptions :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's very informative. I've started looking over that presentation. I'm curious though - with the in-depth answer by creating a virtual representation for every data member/property/function wouldn't the parent class become bloated with values it doesn't actually use which would clutter child classes with options in the IDE? I suppose you could set each as protected and override it in the child as a public?

Comment: *@DivinusVox*: If you keep adding properties & methods to a class, then it *will* eventually become bloated. In all likeliness, the problem will be that you're trying to do too many different things in one place, and thus your class would violate the **[Single Responsiblity Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**. I can't go into details here, but there are ways to correct this. Splitting up your class into several classes, each with a dedicated purpose, is one. -- And no, in C#, once a method has been declared `protected`, it cannot be redeclared `public`.

Answer (score 11):

> So, in this rudimentary example, I'd have a list of Creatures and would need to be able to call from that the Mana property of any given Magical creature.

Yes, this is possible. Use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Creature> creatures = new List<Creature>();
// populate creatures
var magicalCreatures = creatures.OfType<Magical>();
foreach(var magicalCreature in magicalCreatures) {
    Console.WriteLine(magicalCreature.Mana);
}
```

Comment: So I'm trying some of these methods to get a handle on it. I'm having trouble actually populating the list creatures. The add function that's normally used to pop a variable on doesn't seem to exist. How might I do that?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to figure out why IEnumerable would be preferable over a standard List I was able to implement it in the same way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You need to do a conversion to "Magical" at that point.  For example:

```
Creature aCreature = GetMyCreature();
Magical asMagical = aCreature as Magical; // Using "as" operator..
if (asMagical != null)
    Console.WriteLine(asMagical.Mana);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example you would just need to cast the Creature as Magical, and then call your function. You would then do something like:

```
((Magical)myCreature).Mana = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myCreature is Magical)
{
     var myMagicalCreature = (Magical)myCreature;
     //....access mana, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job:

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    Magical magical = item as Magical;
    if (magical != null)
        magical.Mana = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a property is unique to the child class then you will have to cast it to be the child class to access the property, e.g.

```
foreach(Creature creature in creatures)
{
    Magical magical = creature as Magical;
    if (magical != null)
    {
        // Do something with magical.Mana.
    }
}
```

Or alternatively with LINQ:

```
foreach(Magical magical in creatures.OfType<Magical>())
{
    // Do something with magical.Mana.
}
```

It doesn't make sense to do something like:

```
foreach(Creature creature in creatures)
{
    // Do something with creature.Mana.
}
```

Because your creature might not be a Magical and therefore wouldn't have Mana.

Polymorphism comes in where you have two different things with the same properties.

```
foreach(Creature creature in creatures)
{
    // Do something with creature.AttackValue.
}
```

AttackValue is common to both Creature and Magical so you can happily use it without caring whether it is a Creature or a Magical. And the two could have completely different implementations of AttackValue - you don't care because you are treating them polymorphically.

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance only works one way; all child classes are their parents, but no parent is their child.

To get what you want, you must know the class that you are treating as a Creature is in fact a Magical. You can test this using:

```
//Uses reflection to examine the type; useful in generic-typed situations
bool isMagical = typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(Magical); //generic to T where T:Creature

//A keyword-based statement that basically does the same thing given an instance
bool isMagical = creatureInstance is Magical;
```

If it is feasible, you could provide a non-reflective way to discover this, by declaring something in Creature that must be specified in Magical:

```
public Class Creature
{
   public int HealthPoints {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int AttackValue {get; set;}
   public abstract CreatureType Type {get;}

   public Creature();
}

public Class Magical : Creature
{
   public override CreatureType Type {get{return CreatureType.Magical;}}
   public int Mana {get; set;}
}

...

if(creatureInstance.Type == CreatureType.Magical) {...}
```

Once you know the Creature is a Magical, you can treat the instance as its subclass by casting:

```
//Direct cast; throws an InvalidCastException if creatureInstance isn't Magical
var mana = ((Magical)creatureInstance).Mana;

//Safe cast - returns null if creatureInstance isn't Magical,
//which in this usage will throw a NullReferenceException anyway
var mana = (creatureInstance as Magical).Mana;
```